# Include heading title in lower level heading (MS WORD)

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a multi level document in which I use the same each h2, h3, etc., under a varying h1.

I want to define the h2 and lower styles to automatically start with the h1 text.

> For example:
>
> h1 is a certain object name
>
> h2 is "Properties"

I want the following:

## Document

### Document Properties

## File

### File Properties

> where the words "Document" and "File" are inserted automatically, because that is the text of the h1 that the h2 is under.

Can this be done? I didn't find any such definitions in the style settings, maybe there's a macro?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Outline view** to configure it. Click **View** > **Outline**. You can select the heading title and set **Level** for them one by one:
[image]

Comment: i have reworded the question to emphasize what i am after. This answer does not help